# React: how to set initial random useState value without useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display 2 different DIVs randomly: one or another. So I try to keep a random boolean state variable and do the render depending on it.

Let's try to display BLUE sign in the blue box, and RED sign in the red box, for simplicity.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Loader = () => {

  const [redLoader, setRedLoader] = useState(Math.random() < 0.5);

  const loader = redLoader ?
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }} key="red">
      <div>RED</div>
    </div>:
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }} key="blue">
      <div>BLUE</div>
    </div>

  return (
    <div className="full-screen-loader">
      {loader}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Loader;
```

But sometimes I see the BLUE sign in the red box, for example.
[just example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y74OX.png)

So React renders children from another parent.
If I define my random boolean variable out of the Component, nothing changes.
The only thing I can do is set the random `redLoader` variable inside `useEffect`, and then this will work.

So how can I define random state variable before the render, not in `useEffect`?
And why does React behave like this?

React version: 16.13.1

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the described behavior with the code shown.  What do you mean by *"React renders children from another parent"*?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  (Even if it needs to be reloaded repeatedly due to the randomness?)

Comment: Based on your code that would never happen. Can you add a [mcve] to the question so we can see what's going on?

Comment: The reason why you need to use an useState variable is that you eventually need to change its value. In your code, you don't change it, Why you don't only use a normal variable assignment? Remember useState is asynchronous.

Comment: @jircdeveloper I use the state variable because the "ordinary" variable will re-init on every render. So my boolean might change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you should use a useRef instead of useState: this will persist your data but will not cause a rerender.

```
 const redLoader = useRef(Math.random() < 0.5);

// code

  const loader = redLoader.current ?
// more code
```